How can I input multiple custom images in the form of data instead of background, and control the display of the images through the slider?
My plotly version is 2.24.1
This is what I generated with a set of code before, but this can’t complete the image switching.I didn't use the frame format, but this method seems to have problems.This generated html file, I input 5 pictures, there are sliders and pictures, but the pictures can't move according to the movement of the slider, only the first picture is displayed
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import base64
import os

from PIL import Image

folder_path = “/XXX/visualize/gt/multiview”
file_names = os.listdir(folder_path)
img_paths = [os.path.join(folder_path, file_name) for file_name in file_names if file_name.endswith((“.png”, “.jpg”, “.jpeg”))]
fig = go.Figure()

visible = [False] * len(img_paths)
visible[0] = True

steps = 
for i in range(5):
onestep = dict(
method=“update”,
args=[{“visible”: [(j == i) for j in range(5)]}],
label=f"Image {i+1}"
)

steps.append(onestep)
for i, img_path in enumerate(img_paths[:5]):
with open(img_path, “rb”) as img_file:
img_data = base64.b64encode(img_file.read()).decode()

img = Image.open(img_path)
imwidth, imheight = img.size

fig.add_layout_image(
    source="data:image/png;base64," + img_data,
    x=0,
    y=imheight,
    xref="x",
    yref="y",
    sizex=imwidth,
    sizey=imheight,
    opacity=1.0,
    visible=steps[0]["args"][0]["visible"][i],  
    # visible=(i == 3),
    layer="below"
)
sliders = [dict(
active=0,
# currentvalue={“prefix”: "Image: "},
steps=steps
)]

fig.update_layout(
sliders=sliders,
xaxis=dict(
range=[0, imwidth],
showgrid=False,
),
yaxis=dict(
range=[0, imheight],
showgrid=False,
scaleanchor=‘x’,
),
)

output_folder = “/XXX/visualize/plotly”
output_filename = “act0_vis3_0.html”
output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, output_filename)
fig.write_html(output_path)

This is the modified code I made based on the reference code for generating a 3D scatter plot. I thought that the format of custom image input was the same as loading 3D data. With the same data format, I could control the changes of the 3D scatter plot by sliding the slider, but the images were actually different. The image format could not be passed. I tried another set of code before, which was implemented through visible, but it could only display the first image and could not control the slider.
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import base64
import os

from PIL import Image

folder_path = "XXX/visualize/gt/multiview"
file_names = os.listdir(folder_path)
img_paths = [os.path.join(folder_path, file_name) for file_name in file_names if file_name.endswith((".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg"))]
# make figure
fig_dict = {
    "data": [],
    "layout": {},
    "frames": []
}

# fill in most of layout
fig_dict["layout"]["hovermode"] = "closest"
fig_dict["layout"]["updatemenus"] = [
    {
        "buttons": [
            {
                "args": [None, {"frame": {"duration": 500, "redraw": True},
                                "fromcurrent": True, "transition": {"duration": 300,
                                                                    "easing": "quadratic-in-out"}}],
                "label": "Play",
                "method": "animate"
            },
            {
                "args": [[None], {"frame": {"duration": 0, "redraw": True},
                                  "mode": "immediate",
                                  "transition": {"duration": 0}}],
                "label": "Pause",
                "method": "animate"
            }
        ],
        "direction": "left",
        "pad": {"r": 10, "t": 87},
        "showactive": False,
        "type": "buttons",
        "x": 0.1,
        "xanchor": "right",
        "y": 0,
        "yanchor": "top"
    }
]
sliders_dict = {
    "active": 0,
    "yanchor": "top",
    "xanchor": "left",
    "currentvalue": {
        "font": {"size": 20},
        "prefix": "Frame:",
        "visible": True,
        "xanchor": "right"
    },
    "transition": {"duration": 300, "easing": "cubic-in-out"},
    "pad": {"b": 10, "t": 50},
    "len": 0.9,
    "x": 0.1,
    "y": 0,
    "steps": []
}
with open(img_paths[0], "rb") as img_file:
    img_data = base64.b64encode(img_file.read()).decode()

img = Image.open(img_paths[0])
imwidth, imheight = img.size
# make data
image_dict = go.layout.Image(
            source="data:image/png;base64," + img_data,
            x=0,
            y=imheight,
            xref="x",
            yref="y",
            sizex=imwidth,
            sizey=imheight,
            opacity=1.0,
            visible=True,  
            layer="below"
        )
fig_dict["data"].append(image_dict)
   
for i, img_path in enumerate(img_paths[:5]):
    frame = {"data": [], "name": str(i+1)}

    with open(img_path, "rb") as img_file:
        img_data = base64.b64encode(img_file.read()).decode()

    img = Image.open(img_path)
    imwidth, imheight = img.size

    image_dict = go.layout.Image(
            source="data:image/png;base64," + img_data,
            x=0,
            y=imheight,
            xref="x",
            yref="y",
            sizex=imwidth,
            sizey=imheight,
            opacity=1.0,
            visible=(i==0),  
            layer="below"
        )
    frame["data"].append(image_dict)
    fig_dict["frames"].append(frame)

    slider_step = {
        "args": [
            [str(i+1)],
            {"frame": {"duration": 300, "redraw": True},
            "mode": "immediate",
            "transition": {"duration": 300},
            "visible": [(j == i) for j in range(5)]}  
        ],
        "label": f"Image {i+1}",
        "method": "animate"
    }
    # fig_dict["layout"]["sliders"][0]["steps"].append(slider_step)
    sliders_dict["steps"].append(slider_step)

import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
fig_dict["layout"]["sliders"] = [sliders_dict]

fig = go.Figure(fig_dict)

fig.update_layout(
    sliders=sliders,
    xaxis=dict(
        range=[0, 1600],  
        showgrid=False,
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        range=[0, 900],  
        showgrid=False,
        scaleanchor='x',
    ),
)

output_folder = "/xxx/visualize/plotly"
output_filename = "multiphoto1.html"
output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, output_filename)
pio.write_html(fig, output_path)

